# Nexus Jasper Repository

Tags: maven, nexus

In order to get Itext-2.1.7JS I need to add proxy repository to my Nexus OSS.
If I use URL http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/
for crated proxy Repo I don't get access to indexes. Why is this happening?

Comment: iText 2.1.7 (a release that dates from July 2009) has been declared dead years ago. At iText Group, we've removed all instances of iText 2.1.7 form all the servers we had access to a long time ago. There are probably still many places where people can download copies, but maybe some mirror sites are finally realizing that iText 2.1.7 should no longer be used because of the known technical and legal issues with that old iText version. In any case: we no longer support it at iText Group. We don't consider this to be an iText® question (in spite of the tag).

Comment: In addition to what Bruno wrote above, itext-2.1.7JS (note the JS at the end) is a modified version of iText, to be used by, and provided by, Jasper Reports. Have you contacted the Jaspersoft Community at http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library ? Because if you use their maven repo and it doesn't work, they should be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your original question, the remote doesn't publish search indexes.

You can test for this by trying to retrieve the index properties file from the remote:

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties

Search indexes are an optional repository feature used by tools such Nexus and m2Eclipse to support searching of the remote repository.  They are not used by Maven, and are not needed for Maven artifact retrieval to work.  The proxy will work when you run builds against it.

Comment: Yes, I already found it odd that *I* could find a file http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/maven-metadata.xml on the URL he gave, and that it still wouldn't work for him. So his question was actually about an optional Maven feature, not about Jasper Reports or about iText.

Comment: It worked. After I refreshed Nexus group, it was pulled in my project without indexes. Thanks to all of you.